# Set of densities of spectral measures

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory

Let $(X,\mathbb{A},E)$ be a spectral measure on Hilbert space $H$ and $f,g \in H$. We can define scalar measures $\mu_{f,g}(\delta)=(E(\delta)f,g)$ and $\mu_{g}(\delta)=(E(\delta)g,g)$. Now fix $g$. It is clear that $\mu_{f,g}$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu_{g}$. What can we say about the set of densities $D=\displaystyle\bigg\{\frac{d\mu_{f,g}}{d\mu_{g}}\bigg\}_{f\in H}$. My hypothesis is that $D=L^1(X,\mu_{g})$. Inclusion $D\subset L^1(X,\mu_{g})$ is obvious. But if $\phi \in L^1(X,\mu_{g})$ is given,  how can we construct $f \in H$ s.t. $(E(\delta)f,g)=\displaystyle\int\limits_{\delta}\phi d\mu_{g}$ for every $\delta \in \mathbb{A}$? All my attempts failed.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{H}=L^2(0,1)$ and $E(\delta)f=\chi_{(0,\delta)}f,$ where
$\chi_A$ denotes the indicator function of the set $A.$ Then
$$\mu_{f,g}(\delta)=\int\limits_0^\delta f(x)\bar{g}(x)\,dx $$
Let $g(x)\equiv 1.$ Then $d\mu_g=dx$ and $${d\mu_{f,g}\over d\mu_{g}}=f$$
In this case the set $D$ coincides with $L^2(0,1)\subsetneq L^1((0,1).$

The same holds for any $g\in L^2(0,1).$ In this case
$d\mu_g(x)=|g(x)|^2\,dx$ and
$$\mu_{f,g}(\delta)=\int\limits_0^\delta f(x)\bar{g}(x)\,dx=
 \int\limits_0^\delta{f(x)\over g(x)}\,\chi_{\{x\,:\, g(x)\neq 0\}}\,|g(x)|^2\,dx$$
The density belongs to $L^2(\mu_g).$